# How debugging in LWC is significantly easier than Aura Lightning Components?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

We can debug through developer tools in Chrome but LWC doesn't seem to be easier to debug than Aura Lightning Components? We have to click on pretty print to debug LWC. Also we cannot make change on the go as it is pretty print display. Code doesn't look exactly the same. I can see t.variable name and all.
How debugging is easier in LWC than Aura?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say it's easier than in Aura, but I'd suggest enabling Debug Mode. Have you tried it? See [this post](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/02/debug-your-lightning-web-components) for more info.